# Does this "formula" calculate the largest odd divisor of $n^2+1$ ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, recreational-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

I was playing around and came up with the following formula: Let $d(x)$ be the divisor counting function and $(x,y)$ be the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$. If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ I write $$q_n={n^2+1 \above 1.5pt \left(n^2+1,d\left(n^2+1\right)\right)}$$

The formula seems circuitous but it appears that $q_n=$[A228564](http://oeis.org/A228564); the largest odd divisor of $n^2+1$. It appears we have the following identities:

- $\left(q_{n+1},q_n\right)=$[A109009](http://oeis.org/A109009)
- ${q_n-1 \above 1.2pt 4}=$[A123596](http://oeis.org/A123596)
- ${q_n-1 \above 1.2pt 4}=$[A061066](http://oeis.org/A061066) if $n$ is
  prime.
- ${q_{n+2}-q_n \above 1.2 pt 4}=$[A026741](http://oeis.org/A026741)
- ${q_{n+1}+q_n-1 \above 1.2pt 4}=$[A001318](http://oeis.org/A001318)
- ${q_{n+2}+q_n-1 \above 1.2pt 4}=$[A147685](http://oeis.org/A147685)
- ${q_{n+7}+q_{n+6}+q_{n+5}+q_{n+4}-q_{n+3}-q_{n+2}-q_{n+1}-q_n-1
     \above 1.2pt 4}=$ [A09225](http://oeis.org/A092259) for $n>3$

My question is straightforward:

> Is $q_n$ the largest odd divisor of $n^2+1$ and if so why?

If this is not true a disproof or counter example suffices. I have only checked the first 50 or so terms. Note if this result is true and the second identity is true then for $n^2+1$ prime we have $n^2+1=4k+1$ where $k\in$[A123596](http://oeis.org/A123596). Subtracting $1$ from both sides gives us $n^2=4k=$[A075408](https://oeis.org/A075408). So $n=4\sqrt k$ and $k$ must be a square. In fact I have that $k$ is actually in a much smaller and sparse subset of A123596 namely $k\in$[A230312](https://oeis.org/A230312). Suprisingly in a round about fashion using this "formula" I got the following result:

If $q_n$ and $n$ are prime and $\sigma_1\left(n^2+1\right)$ is the sum off all divisors of $n^2+1$ then $$\sigma_1\left(n^2+1\right)=12*A123596+6$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first counterexample is $n=443$, for which $\frac{n^2+1}{q_n} = 10$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: Could you show the calculation explicitly.

Comment: ^It appears you are correct. My claim is false after the 443 term.

Comment: Curiosly $\frac{n^2+1}{(n^2+1,2^{d(n^2+1)})}$ computes the correct terms.